# Is there a way to mutate a neural network in tensorflow/keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, evolutionary-algorithm

I would like to create a neuroevolution project using python and tensorflow/keras but I couldn't find any good way of mutating the neural network.

I am aware that there are librarys like NEAT, but I wanted to try and code it myself.
Would appreciate it if anyone can tell me something.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit too vague, but I would assume that coding your own evolutionary algorithm shouldn’t be too difficult for you given what you have done with neural networks so far.

A good starting point for you would be to research the following EA concepts…

1. Encoding.
2. Fitness.
3. Crossover and/or Mutation.

Comment: yes, I know but I mean if there is any function in tensorflow/keras that allows you to mutate your neural network

Comment: I apologize, I have misunderstood your original question. There is no function that I am aware of in tensorflow that will mutate a NN for you. You'll need to cobble together some code that will randomly change the parameters of a given NN.

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware that there are librarys like NEAT, but I wanted to try and code it myself.

But for other people visiting this question that are interested in neuro-evolution in TF/Keras: have a look at the [NeuralFit](https://neuralfit.net/) library. It does not do the mutations in Keras, but it allows you to export the model to Keras. A small example (adapted from their [Github page](https://github.com/neural-fit/neuralfit)):

```py
import neuralfit as nf
import numpy as np

# Define dataset (XOR gate)
x = np.asarray([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
y = np.asarray([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

# Define model (2 inputs, 1 output)
model = nf.Model(2, 1)

# Compile and evolve
model.compile('alpha', loss='mse', monitors=['size'])
model.evolve(x,y)

# Export model to Keras
keras_model = model.to_keras()
```